# Форматирование даты в моделе

Tags: c#, валидация, datetime

Как мне в моделе поменять формат даты?
В данный момент так:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? DateTimeStart { get; set; }//начало действия
```

на клиенте есть валидация. Клиент отсылает на сервер `10.05.2019 12:12:12` - и все ок. А если отослать `14.05.2019 12:12:12` то вылазит ошибка `The field Время начала must be a date`.

Т е `DataFormatString` игнорируется и он все равно думает что первый идет месяц.

Почему так и как это исправить без смены культуры или сразу для всех культур???

Comment: у вас asp.net классический, asp.net core, либо сочетание с каким-нибудь фреймворком на фронте типа react/angular/vue? Не вижу ни в метках вопроса, ни в самом вопросе. Вопрос в общих чертах понятен, но тут столько может быть мелочей, которые по-разному влияют на воспроизводимость ошибки, что я бы попросил ещё и код экшена показать. У вас со строки идёт, с json? Какая культура выставлена на сервере?

Comment: @AK asp.net mvc 5

Comment: парсится отосланное значение на основе культуры установленной на сервере.

Comment: @Grundy мне нужно не зависимо от культуры установить формат именно на сервере...такое возможно?

Comment: [Custom DateTime model binder in Asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2356601/2881286)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо большое